# Welcome, Username and Displaying random image from folder

Tags: php, random, session-variables

I'm trying to fix up a pre-existing website and add dynamic information. I need to add Welcome, $user with the username coming from session.php and only displaying if they are logged on. Then I need to add images from a /images/banner/ folder to display dynamically, only one at a time.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php session_start();
    require_once ("Includes/simplecms-config.php"); 
    require_once  ("Includes/connectDB.php");
    require_once ('Includes/session.php");
    include("Includes/header.php");         
 ?>


<div id="container">

<?php

$user = $_SESSION['username'];

echo "Welcome $user";

?>

<div id="tagline">Welcome to Sally's diner!</div>
    <div id="banner"><img src="Images/banner/1.jpg" /></div>

</div>

</div> <!-- End of outer-wrapper which opens in header.php -->

<?php 
include ("Includes/footer.php");
?>
```

1. I keep getting a syntax error on line 14 which is $user = $_SESSION['username'];
2. How do I display an image from /Images/banner/ folder where there are more than one images and only display one image at a time.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Vanessa

Comment: What specific error are you getting? Incidentally, there's a quote mismatch on line 4 -- the code highlighting reveals it.

Comment: include("Includes/header.php"); 1st remove this line and try, also change echo "Welcome $user"; to echo "Welcome ".$user; if it works, then put back, but it should be include "Includes/header.php";

Comment: @MarkNg Why? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with either of those statements.

Comment: If the syntax error isn't on the line indicated, look at the lines above it, in this case line 4 as showdev has pointed out is the culprit ( require_once ('Includes/session.php");  ) starts with a single quote, which is then not ended until line 14 where the next single quote is found.

Answer (score 2):

1. What @showdev wrote in his comment.
2. To get a random image out of the folder (in PHP):

   ```
   $yourdir = "/Images/banner/";

   function getext($file) {
       if(strstr($file,'/')) {
           $file = explode('/', $file);
           $file = end($file);
       }

       if(strstr($file,'.')) {
           $file = explode('.', $file);
           $result = end($file);
       } else {
           $result = false;
       }

       return $result;
   }    

   function listSlideshowItems($dir) {
       $dir = rtrim($dir, '\\/');
       $result = array();

       if (file_exists($dir) && is_dir($dir)) {
           foreach (preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($dir)) as $f) {
               if (!is_dir("$dir/$f")) {
                   if (strtolower(getext($f)) == 'png' || strtolower(getext($f)) == 'jpg') {
                       $result[] = $f;
                   }
               }
           }
           return $result;
       } else {
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

Then call the function:

```
$images = listSlideshowItems($yourdir);
```

`print_r($images);` will give an output like this:

*Array ( [0] => 0.jpg [1] => 1.jpg [2] => 2.jpg [3] => 3.jpg [4] => 4.jpg )*

Then shuffle the array: `shuffle($images);`

`print_r($images);` will now give an output shuffeled, for example:

*Array ( [0] => 1.jpg [1] => 4.jpg [2] => 3.jpg [3] => 2.jpg [4] => 0.jpg )*

Just pick the first and you have a random filename of an image in your *images* folder: `$filename = $images[0]`

Do what you need for your application with it, for example:

```
<img src="<?php echo $yourdir . $filename; ?>" alt="">
```